# How to move the ID to inside an object when it is outside the object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array which has some objects inside. Each object has an id outside of it, but I would like to insert that ID inside the object.

**This is the array:**

```
'DISCOUNTS2: ', [ { id: 'discount1',
                         │ data:
                         │ { food_description: 'kifle me mermelad dhe nutella',
                         │ time: '22:00',
                         │ price: '1',
                         │ amount: 4,
                         │ food_name: 'kifle',
                         │ rest_id: '1' } },
                      { id: 'ai34Lyk9uXtpGDcCKfqa',
                         │ data:
                         │ { food_description: 'fsdfdsfdsf',
                         │ time: '345345',
                         │ price: '6',
                         │ amount: 4,
                         │ food_name: 'sdsddsf',
                         │ rest_id: '5' } },
                      { id: 'discount3',
                         │ data:
                         │ { food_description: 'torte me dredheza',
                         │ time: '18:00',
                         │ price: '3',
                         │ amount: 5,
                         │ food_name: 'torte',
                         │ rest_id: 'Aura1' } },
                      { id: 'discount2',
                         │ data:
                         │ { food_description: 'byrek me mish dhe djath',
                         │ time: '20:00',
                         │ price: '0.50',
                         │ amount: 6,
                         │ food_name: 'byrek',
                         └ rest_id: 'jeta1' } } ]
```

**This is the code where  I am inserting the data inside the array:**

```
   var ref = firebase.firestore().collection('discounts')
                .orderBy('rest_id')
                .limit(this.state.limit)
            ref.onSnapshot((querySnapshot => {
                var discounts = querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => { return { id: doc.id, data: doc.data() } });
                var lastVisibleDiscount = discounts[discounts.length - 1].rest_id;
                this.setState({
                    discounts: discounts,
                    lastVisibleDiscount: lastVisibleDiscount,
                    loading: false,
                });
            }));
```

Comment: How would it look after the id is moved inside?

Comment: @Yousername here is one object example: { id:'discount2', food_description: 'byrek me mish dhe djath',
                         │ time: '20:00',
                         │ price: '0.50',
                         │ amount: 6,
                         │ food_name: 'byrek',
                         └ rest_id: 'jeta1' } }

Comment: What are those pipe symbols, which make the data object invalid?

Comment: You should be able to do something like this `var discounts = querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => { return { data: { ...doc.data(), id: doc.id } } });`, although I would prob do something like this, to keep the objects in an array without a `data` key `var discounts = querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => return { { ...doc.data(), id: doc.id } });` keep in mind I have not tested this

Comment: @trincot sorry, I just copied it like that from the console.

Comment: @trincot I highly doubt the pipes are contained in the actual code........

Comment: @MattOestreich, I also doubt that. Those asking questions should therefore do the effort to post valid code & object literals.

Comment: @trincot fair enough - I can't disagree with that. You're right.

Comment: @Roope instead, why don't you use the same time to post an answer and help out?!

Comment: @Roope you're right - I can't argue with that.  At the end of the day I agree with you, the 'asker' shouldn't make 'answerers' assume anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code, just add the `id` when you get it. Replace this:

```
var discounts = querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => { return { id: doc.id, data: doc.data() } });
```

with this:

```
var discounts = querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => ({ id: doc.id, ...doc.data() }));
```

Note that you will have a more flat structure. There is no more wrapping object with `id` and `data` properties. The array will have the data objects immediately, including the `id` property.

Comment: @MattOestreich your answer helped me out, this seems like a copy of yours but explained in a bit more details, thanks both!

Comment: I think due to the fact that I should have posted my comment as an answer to begin with, @trincot should be the accepted answer.

Comment: @MattOestreich, Let me find a good answer you made recently, to upvote it as compensation -- to be honest I had not seen your comment. Several people can come up with the same thing independently.

Comment: @trincot no harm, no foul. You are correct in this scenario and if anything taught me a lesson, which means more than upvotes, in my opinion. Cheers!

Comment: @trincot I say upvote this question instead of upvoting an older answer of mine :) show OP some love :)

Comment: @trincot you're a man of your word. I thank you. Hope you have a good day! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try iterating over the array, then adding a key to the data object and finally, you can delete the id key from the parent object. It can be like this:

```
  // Assuming the array discounts exists and has data
  discounts.forEach(prod => {
      let id = prod.id;
      prod.data.id = id;
      delete prod.id;
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Array.map()`. I returned `obj.data` to flatten the object structure, but if you want to keep it just return `obj` instead:

```js
const arr = [{id:'discount1',data:{food_description:'kifle me mermelad dhe nutella',time:'22:00',price:'1',amount:4,food_name:'kifle',rest_id:'1'}},{id:'ai34Lyk9uXtpGDcCKfqa',data:{food_description:'fsdfdsfdsf',time:'345345',price:'6',amount:4,food_name:'sdsddsf',rest_id:'5'}},{id:'discount3',data:{food_description:'torte me dredheza',time:'18:00',price:'3',amount:5,food_name:'torte',rest_id:'Aura1'}},{id:'discount2',data:{food_description:'byrek me mish dhe djath',time:'20:00',price:'0.50',amount:6,food_name:'byrek',rest_id:'jeta1'}}]

const res = arr.map(obj => {
    obj.data.id = obj.id
    delete obj.id
    return obj.data
})

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you can use [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).

```
const data = [{
  id: 'discount1',
  data:
  {
    food_description: 'kifle me mermelad dhe nutella',
    time: '22:00',
    price: '1',
    amount: 4,
    food_name: 'kifle',
    rest_id: '1'
  }
},
// and the rest of the array
];
const res = data.map(elem => ({ id: elem.id, ...elem.data }));

// which, when printed, you would get: 

[ { id: 'discount1', 
    food_description: 'kifle me mermelad dhe nutella', 
    time: '22:00', 
    price: '1', 
    amount: 4, 
    food_name: 'kifle', 
    rest_id: '1' }
// ... and the rest of the converted array 
]
```